# ASP.NET Core Web API (OpenAPI) Client issue with NSwag toolchain

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I wonder if you can help. I'm using VS 2022 and trying to create a client to consume a Web API with open API. Essentially I'm using this older .NET 5.0 explanation -

https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/generate-client-for-asp-net-core-web-api-using-openapi

I add the Connected Service - OpenAPI Service Reference, the OpenAPI classes are automatically produced with the NSwag toolchain.

As soon as that happens the auto-generated code then flags an error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EnumMemberAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Specifically :

```
var attribute = System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute)) 
                            as System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute;
```

Looking on MS seems to suggest that EnumMemberAttribute is indeed part of Serialization -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=net-6.0

As I say, this code is automatically generated so I don't understand why the VS22 IDE would flag this?

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you don't install the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives` package. It provides common types, including System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute, for libraries that support data contract serialization.

[image]

Please install it and add the using for the EnumMemberAttribute.

Comment: Yes that has resolved the issue, thanks.

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, it will help other folks who face the same issue could find the answer more easily.